# Invoking a constructor other than the default constructor for a self created object

Tags: java, web-services, constructor

I have a web service method to take my own type object parameter and return it back after concatenating two strings of the parameter. This is my data type

```
public class MyType implements Serializable{
    String fName;
    String lName;

    public MyType(){
        fName="fname";
        lName="lanme";
    }

    public MyType(String s1, String s2) {
        fName = s1;
        lName = s2;
    }

}
```

NetBeans did not allow me to deploy the web service with out the no argument constructor.  This is my code part of the web service.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "objectMethod")
public String objectMethod(@WebParam(name = "parameter") MyType parameter) {
    //TODO write your implementation code here:
    String s1=parameter.fName;
    String s2 = " Darshana ";
    String s=s1.concat(s2.concat(parameter.lName));
    return s;
}
```

I am invoking this web service method by using an android application. It gives the output as `fname Darshana lname`. `fname` and `lname` are the values I have given in the no argument constructor for `MyType`. 
I am passing a same type object from the android application. I need to invoke the second constructor of the `MyType` class.
How do I need to change my web service method for that?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding accessors and mutators to `MyType`? Also, why did you post a `TODO` comment with your question?

Comment: Sorry for TODO comments.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you get a JavaBean. So you have to write it as a Bean. Add accessors and mutators.

Comment: I did not add setters and getters. After adding it how can I call them

Comment: You don't have to, the injected MyType will be set by the container.